# getting the next key in a set of keys (circular) in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6};
```

Note that this is not an array (unless it is in JS and there is a way to map them)

I now have a requirement to get the next key, given a key. It also needs to be 'circular'. So `findNext('c')` should be `d`, while `findNext('f')` should be `a`

Here is what I came up with:

```js
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6};
console.log ( findNext('e',obj), " is after e" );
console.log ( findNext('f',obj), " is after f" );
console.log ( findNext('a',obj), " is after a" );



function findNext (key,obj)
{
   var size = Object.keys(obj).length;
   var i;
   for (i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
      if (Object.keys(obj)[i] == key)
      break;
   }
   i = (i + 1) % size;
   return Object.keys(obj)[i];
   
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, given that all keys are a hash? Can I avoid not having to iterate till X to find next(X) ?

thanks

Comment: define *"next"*. Order of object properties is not consistent depending on how they are constructed and can not be relied upon

Comment: why not just do a `Object.keys(obj).length` and `if size == Object.keys(obj).length - 1, size = 0?`

Comment: Not quite sure what happened to the answers and comments that were posted to this Q -they disappeared - maybe because someone chose to vote to close this question?
charlietfl - yes, I agree - next would be any one that is next in that particular system when iterating.

A. Lau: Thats what I'm doing in the 2nd to last line? ( % instead of the if)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using

- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [Arithmetic operators - Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

```js
function findNext(key, obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);

  console.log(
    keys[(keys.indexOf(key) + 1) % keys.length]
  );
}

var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6};

findNext('a', obj); // b
findNext('c', obj); // d
findNext('f', obj); // a
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this, Although you'll need to handle the `else`, also I am using `es6` but you can paste on `babel.io` to get the `es5` output

```
let obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6};

const findNext = (key, obj) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const len = Object.keys(obj).length;

  if (keys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
     const nextIndex = (keys.indexOf(key) + 1) % len;
     const next = keys[nextIndex];

     return { [next]: obj[next] };
  }
}
```